# What data types are safe to read and write to after retrieving it from a concurrently accessible structure?

Tags: caching, concurrency, go, mutex, race-condition

Probably not clear from the question itself what I'm after here, so let me clarify.  As an exercise in concurrency, I'm playing around with writing a cache that needs to be accessible by multiple simultaneous requests. Cache content is of type interface{}, so it can include anything, including slices, maps, and structs. When I grab something with a Get method, I RLock on it while reading it and then return the content and finish with a deferred RUnlock.

This works fine for numbers and strings and any other values that are automatically copied on return.  But I'm concerned that slices, maps, and structs are not actually copied, such that the thing returned, if read or modified as if it were a copy, would actually be altering data in the cache and doing so outside of a mutex.

Of course, that's a problem under race conditions. So I don't want to return something from Get that is not safe to alter and then pass back to a Set method to update. So here are the questions:

1) Am I correct in assuming that these data types present problems for a scenario like this?

2) How might one go about resolving this issue, so as to create a Get method whose values can be freely manipulated without fear of failure under race conditions?

Comment: As Ralph points out in his answer, you even have problems with the types you consider "safe," so it's a lot harder than it seems on the surface. The classic example is if you use your cache to implement a counter. Two routines safely `Get` the current value of `1`, increment it, and `Set` it back. Now the counter is erroneously `2` instead of `3`, but access to the cache itself is consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming those kinds of data types mainly references and pointers to structs can cause a problem for the reasons I'll talk about below.

I see really two problems that are you dealing with. The first, is that you need to protect your cache from concurrent access such that the cache is always in a correct state.  If you are mutating the cache and using a "write" lock, your cache will maintain its integrity when it is being changed in some way.  Also, as long as you take a "read" lock when reading from the cache you are guaranteed to read out of your cache with that same integrity. So as it stands, the locks protecting your cache **only work at protecting the cache itself**.  These locks will not do anything to protect the items stored within the cache.

This is the second issue you are dealing with: Assuming your cache is protected, think about what would happen if two separate goroutines do a properly synchronized Get operation from your cache.  They don't necessarily even have to Get the object at the same time but if somehow they end up "getting" a pointer to some struct or a reference to a map/slice this means they could potentially **both mutate the same object** of which they are both holding references to.  This manifests itself as the second problem you are describing.

So what are your options?

1. Only store value types which as you have observed can be limiting and/or expensive because everything must be copied.
2. Only store some custom types that are synchronized by also making sure they take appropriate locks on themselves when they are mutated or read.
3. Make your cache smarter so that it has the concept of ownership where it will gladly return an object from the cache and only ever allow one goroutine to "hold" onto it until that goroutine is finished.  Other goroutines would have to wait for that object to be released until the previous goroutine has finished with it.  Either that, or you could design the Get to fail and return immediately if it tried to Get an item that was currently unavailable. *This concept is widely used to build distributed locks in a client server architecture where there could be many clients that want access to an object and the distributed lock ensures that only one client can ever hold the lock.*

Consider that the concept of ownership is important.  Someone might say: just use channels, that will fix everything.  But you can even end up in the same boat if you send a reference type or a pointer to a struct into 5 different channels.  Those 5 different channels could possibly mutate the same object they are holding onto.  Uh oh! the same problem manifests itself again. This is why it's important that when you pass an item to a channel you are giving up ownership to not mutate it.

As someone told me today...**concurrent programming is hard** and there are probably additional patterns out there you could try but I hope this gives some more insight into the problem you are dealing with.  One thing to know is there isn't really a bullet-proof answer to this, much of it will depend on the nature of how your application behaves ultimately.

Comment: Your answer definitely helps to flesh out the problem further. Seems like there isn't a really great solution. I'm thinking of a scenario where two uniquely keyed structs in the cache reference map X. Even if you have locks on the structs themselves, things could still get racy with the map and fail. Only sure solution to this would be to marshall the data when setting it and unmarshall when retrieving it. Better safe and expensive than efficient and unstable, I guess. Appreciate the detailed answer to get me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Am I correct in assuming that these data types present problems for
>   a scenario like this?

Yes. Maps and slices have pointers to internal data structures that aren't copied during assignment. But since you're using an `interface{}` you could also have structs with pointers, which could point to structs with more pointers and so on.

> 2) How might one go about resolving this issue, so as to create a Get
>   method whose values can be freely manipulated without fear of failure
>   under race conditions?

The easiest solution is to only allow an object to be returned to a single client at a time, so that there's only ever one live, mutable version. You could also serialize the objects, so that everything is always a copy.

*Anything* that needs to be written and read concurrently needs to have proper synchronization. Period.